# How to use Pentax A3000 in dim lighting?

Tags: exposure, film, low-light, pentax, old-cameras

My Pentax A3000 doesn't have shutter speed control, only ISO and a few modes, B (bulb), 60 for flash, program, and aperture. I keep it on program, but what should I do if I want to shoot in darker lighting? Since I'm using 400 speed film, do I have to keep the ISO on 400?

Answer (score 2):

In short: it's kind of a pain, because this camera was targeted at people who didn't want to worry about such things. It *only* has fully-programmed and aperture priority mode. As you've discovered, there's no way to set shutter speed directly (other than bulb or flash sync).

The camera's exposure program uses the built-in meter and automatically matches aperture and shutter values to give its best guess at correct exposure for the scene. (It's not smart — it just assumes what you're pointing at should be average gray.)

It has an "exposure compensation" button, but that is fixed at changing by +1.5 [EV](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19528/what-is-the-ev-scale) — it's meant for the common situation of a shaded subject with a bright background. More sophisticated cameras often have a range of [exposure compensation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/what-is-exposure-compensation) settings.

So, you can, to some degree, fake this by playing with the ISO setting. That setting tells the camera the sensitivity of the film you have loaded — of course, unlike with a digital camera, you can't adjust that from frame to frame, but what you *can* do is trick the camera into giving a brighter exposure by setting the ISO value to be lower than it really is. Then the camera's program will pick a longer shutter speed to get in more light. (Or possibly also wider aperture, if you're in full program rather than aperture-priority mode.)

But, really, I think if you're interested in more control, I suggest you look for a different camera body. The Pentax K1000 is an all-manual model which is [still highly regarded](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/36095/is-a-pentax-k1000-relevant-today-and-how-can-i-get-the-best-use-of-it). It's kind of the opposite of this camera, in that there's *nothing* automatic. (But it does have an easy-to-use exposure needle.)

An aside: if your A3000 came with the 50mm f/1.7 lens, keep that — many other low-cost Pentax cameras have the f/2 instead, and the f/1.7 is *far* superior in every way (not just the faster aperture).